# service worker - Progressive caching for a progressive web app - How to load groups of files step by step

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Here is a service worker that caches only the basic starting files of the app,

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith( caches.match(event.request)
    .then( cachedResponse => {
      return cachedResponse || fetch(event.request);
    } )
  );
});

const cacheName0 = "bare-bones-of-the-app";
const mainResourcesToPrecache = [
"index.html",
"app.js",
"style.css"
];

self.addEventListener("install", event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName0).then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll(mainResourcesToPrecache);
    })
  );
});
```

So far so good.
Now let's say this PWA is a game and the user makes progress as he completes one level after another. And let's say we have,

```
const cacheName1 = "level-1";
const resourcesForLevel1 = [
"somepicture.jpg",
"someartwork.png",
"somesound.mp3"
];
const cacheName2 = "level-2";
const resourcesForLevel2 = [
"anotherpicture.jpg",
"anotherartwork.png",
"anothersound.mp3"
];
// etc
```

In this case how do we wake the service worker up with a function firing in the main thread and thus make the browser **get the files in advance** as the user reaches certain points in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about the Cache Storage API is that the same caches are exposed in both the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` and the `Window` context. So you can do what you're suggesting without having to send a message to the service worker asking it to cache things for you.

The important thing is to make sure that you're using the same cache names in both contexts.

```js
async function cacheLevel(levelNumber) {
  // Make sure this matches the cache name you use in the SW.
  const cacheName = `level-${levelNumber};

  // Assume there's a levelNumber => URLs mapping function.
  const urls = getURLsForLevel(levelNumber);

  const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
  await cache.addAll(urls);
}
```

(Using `postMessage()` to communicate with the service worker is an option as well, but it's not required for your use case.)

Comment: Appreciated. Do you know of any possible situations where caching should be done by the service-worker only? Or are «service-worker» caching and «window» caching exactly the same thing for all scenarios? For example does the reported installation size of the app depend on files being cached by the service-worker?

Comment: It’s the exact same caches. You can access them from either environment.